# Why can't this label in ListView.Header show all text?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Android: 6.0
Xamarin.Forms: 2.1.0.6529

Create a new Xamarin.Forms project and paste this:

```
class Model
{
    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var label = new Label
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
            Text = genLongText(),
            HeightRequest = 10000, // force height
        };

        var list = new List<Model>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new Model { Text = i + " list item" });
        }

        var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
        template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, nameof(Model.Text));

        var listview = new ListView
        {
            Header = label,
            ItemsSource = list,
            ItemTemplate = template,
            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
        };

        var content = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "test",
            Content = listview
        };

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
    }

    private string genLongText()
    {
        var t = " Welcome to Xamarin Forms!\n";
        var s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            s += i.ToString() + t;
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image: Label cropped]

As you can see, **the text is cropped and doesn't show more than the first 100 lines**. The Label itself (yellow background) is fine because I forced the height to be big, **otherwise the height of the label would be also of this same length**.

So, basically if you set a very long text on the label, it will only expand to show the first 100 lines and if you change its height manually through HeightRequest then the label will be fine but the text will still be clipped.

This must be related to ListView.Header implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android, a Form's `ListView` is a `android.widget.ListView` and within that the ListView's header is being set to a `Container` that contains your choice of a `VisualElement`.

Since you are using a Forms' `Label` which is an Android `TextView`, the 100 lines of text is internally set within the Android widget class. Trying to set the height via the Forms' ListViewRenderer.cs Container OnMeasure method  will not override that.

From `ListViewRenderer.cs`

```
int heightSpec = MeasureSpecFactory.MakeMeasureSpec((int)ctx.ToPixels(request.Request.Height), MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
_child.ViewGroup.Measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

If you *really* need to display that much text in a ListView Header **without** creating a custom ListViewRender and manually manipulating the SetLines, SetMinLines and SetMaxLines of the TextView within that Container , use an Forms' `Editor` (disabled) instead as your header's `VisualElement`:

```
var label = new Editor
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
    Text = genLongText(),
    MinimumHeightRequest = 10000,
    IsEnabled = false
};
```

[image]

You can also embed your header disabled `Editor` in a `ScrollView` and assign that as your `ListView` `Header` so you are scroll the text within `Editor`:

```
var scrollViewHeader = new ScrollView
{
    HeightRequest = 200,
    Content = label
};
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using ScrollView, it produces the same problem. How did you get it work? Here is the new code http://pastebin.com/9m60Up9S

Comment: @Spacemonkey My bad on the ScrollView, I had a custom scrollviewrender  attached that re-calcs all the sub-views/children heights... I updated the answer.. if you use a disable Editor within the ScrollView you can achieve the same results.

Comment: Thanks! Scrolling only works nicely inside the emulator using the mouse scroll wheel (middle button). It's hard to make it scroll by dragging. Thought I should let you know. I'll try the other solutions now

Comment: @Spacemonkey A `ScrollView` inside a scrolling `ListView` is an issue, any `ScrollView` within another `ScrollView` can be problematic on different mobile platforms **unless** you handle the touch/drag recognizers yourself. Xamarin has a brief note about not doing that on their site.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've fixed it now using "SetMaxLines(100000)". It is set to 100 by default. You have no idea how much time i wasted on this problem.. I thought it was the Height that needs to be set manually so I calculated what the required height would be to display the whole text and I was setting that.. Now I realise the solution is so simple